# Custom stylesheet in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create custom css, but for some reason my webpack is not picking up css I include.
Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import logo from './logo.svg'; 
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap';    
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome'; 
import './App.css';

class App extends Component { render() { return (...); } }
export default App;
```

App.css contains necessary style descriptions. Here is my package.json http://pastebin.com/GjRbzTW7

Is there anything I can do to debug this? My console seem to show that the elements are loaded under webpack (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8O4x.jpg), but inspecting elements shows no style is applied.

Comment: You need a css-loader. Can I see the webpack.config.js?

Comment: If this is production, you need to use the extracttext plugin and include the lin to the built css file in your HTML. If it's development, don't use the extracttext plugin, and the css will be built into your dev JS bundle

Comment: @AndrewLi Here is output of `cat ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/webpack.config.js`:  http://pastebin.com/sLvADsEN

Comment: @OmarKhazamov in loaders, for css, install the package `css-loader` and change it to `style-loader!css-loader`

Comment: @AndrewLi did the trick, thanks for the answer, sir

Comment: @OmarKhazamov No problem